# JetBrains Rider suggests "make parameter type Component". Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am currently using JetBrains Rider as the IDE.

```
private void RemoveAlert(int idx, Image lockImg)
{
    ...
}
```

While writing the code above, I received a suggestion from Rider to convert the Image type parameter of the RemoveAlert method to a Component. I do not know why.

I wonder if this proposal is more efficient or customary. If you know anything, please answer.

Screenshot for the suggestion from Rider:

[image]

Comment: If you write a method that takes a `Dog` but you never call `Bark`, you might as well have made it take `Animal`, and then *it becomes a more useful method* because there are more possible ways to call it.

Comment: You are using Rider, then it has nothing to do with ReSharper (which is a VS addin). They share the same language engine and many other features, but they are different products.

Comment: BTW Re# and Rider share also resharper-unity plugin https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity
In Rider it is bundled, in Re# it can be explicitly installed.

Comment: @LexLi: The Rider documentation and marketing explicitly states that it makes use of Resharper inspections.  Further, the syntax for enabling/disabling inspections in rider is still `// ReSharper disable [inspection id]`.  A question could be rider-specific or Resharper-specific, but this question applies to both.  While a pedant might say you are technically correct to say this is not a Resharper question, OP can happily accept answers from Resharper experts and Resharper users can happily consult this question for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see exactly how you're using the variable (the hover-text is covering some stuff) but ReSharper will suggest this when you're using a derived class but not any of its extra functionality.  It looks like you're getting a reference to its `gameObject` property, and if you look at the inheritance hierarchy, `Component` is the lowest-level class that has that property:

```txt
UnityEngine.UI.Image
UnityEngine.UI.MaskableGraphic
UnityEngine.UI.Graphic
UnityEngine.EventSystems.UIBehaviour 
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
UnityEngine.Behaviour
UnityEngine.Component <- has gameObject property
UnityEngine.Object    <- doesn't have gameObject property
```

---

Also, if you find this annoying, you can put the following over the function:

```
// ReSharper disable once SuggestBaseTypeForParameter
```

Or you can put this at the top of the file itself to cover all its functions:

```
// ReSharper disable SuggestBaseTypeForParameter
```